# Do you think Zend framework misses the Symfony's Bundle principle ?

Tags: zend-framework, symfony

I have been working in ZF since it was v1.6  and i am pretty happy with it , but reading about symfony and its bundle principle :

to make sumfony Bundle more clear :

http://docs.symfony-reloaded.org/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

> But what is a bundle? All the code you
>   write in a Symfony2 project is
>   organized in bundles. In Symfony2
>   speak, a bundle is a structured set of
>   files (PHP files, stylesheets,
>   JavaScripts, images, ...) that
>   implements a single feature (a blog, a
>   forum, ...) and which can be easily
>   shared with other developers. In our
>   example, we only have one bundle,
>   HelloBundle.

i was using the same idea by organizing my code in modules , but this is really painful

any body has same `bundle` implementation for ZF ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some effort to archieve this, but mainly it's PITA to do this in ZF. But you can actually use the Symfony's infrastructure and still use all Zend's classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's a real PITA to come close to achieve what Symfony2 is doing with their bundles. I had to extend ZF with a lot of code to come close to an extension structure (see [Majisti](https://github.com/majisti/majisti)), which is barely as good as what Symfony2 is offering. I agree with Tomas: Symfony2 with ZF2 classes, IMO I don't think ZF2 will compete high enough in the full-stack department.