# Zend Framework or Symfony

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1

I am in the process of migrating to a new PHP Framework. I have been involved in heavy development using the CodeIgniter Framework, but I am finding it a little too lightweight for my needs now.

I have boiled my choices down to either Zend Framework or Symfony. I know the learning curve for both is relatively high. However, I just wanted to get a rough idea of which will be worth getting stuck into (as I will be spending quite a lot of time getting familiar with the chosen framework).

If it helps narrow the answer down a little. I am not looking to build a simple blog or anything like that. I am in need for something that will support full-fledged development of e-commerce systems, customer relationship managers and content management systems.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677485/zend-vs-symfony-development-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469807/zend-vs-symfony-learning-time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally i have been working with ZF since it was in version  1.6, and i am pretty happy with it , I had seen very good improvement  since 1.6  , but i think ZF missing some ideas :

1- ORM and later on very great implementation between ZF + Doctrine 1.2 has taken very popularity 
and i honestly depend on ZF + Doctrine in many projects 
and these days we can see great integration between ZF + Doctrine2

2- the symfony's bundle is completely forgotten in ZF 
[Do you think Zend framework misses the Symfony's Bundle principle ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053369/do-you-think-zend-framework-misses-the-symfonys-bundle-principle)
and i think its really indeed to see it soon (hopefully in ZF 2 )

3- i had many good points about symfony 1

```
     - doctrine built in support 
     - bundle principle 
     - admin generators which can  save a lot of time
     - symfony plugins is very popular 
     - symfony documentation is really good
```

finally , i had took a  deep look at  symfony 1 but i am really taken by the buzz of symfony2 in the late of 2010 and till today its public preview http://symfony.com/download 
and i am trying to spend some time learning it  .

wish me luck :)

**update**
I don't want my answer to imply that ZF isn't good or symfony is better than ZF , ZF IMO very powerful library and being ZF developer === advanced + powerful PHP OOP programmer .

Comment: If you want to integrate Doctrine2 with ZF apps, just have a look at the [Zend Framework Webinars](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework) page, and watch the Zend Framework v1 + Doctrine v2 webinar. I use Propel as ORM layer in combination with ZF on a daily basis (just add an extra _init to your bootstrap to initialize Propel and you're good to go). As for the bundles : that would indeed be a nice addition.

Answer (score 9):

I had to make this choice about 1.5 years ago. I first looked at ZF and read up on it as much as possible, but at the end of the day I never really felt comfortable with it. It felt over-engineered, and I found myself getting lost in the code pretty often. I then checked out Symfony with Doctrine. I was able to come to grips with the code base much quicker than ZF. I've since used Symfony on 30+ projects, everything ranging from small sites to pretty large applications and I couldn't be happier. Their admin generator tools have cut down the time I spend building CMS's by a ridiculous amount, and I'm constantly adding my own additions so that future projects take even less time. On top of that, their routing framework, forms framework, and plugin architecture are very well built and very useful. (And Doctrine is a God-send, but you can use that with ZF as well, it's just nice that Symfony uses it by default and has some tighter integration with it.)

Luckily, both ZF and Symfony are highly extensible, so whichever you choose, you'll be better off than using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would rather invest my time in learning the Zend framework. I've played with symfony in the past, and it does have its merits, but I like the Zend framework better. For me Symfony (1.x) has that "things patched together with duct tape" feel around it. There's a lot of different plugins, with varying code quality. ZF tries to raise the bar and feels like a more professional, and well thought out framework (and on top of that ZF is very flexible). Symfony might be better suited for prototyping though because of the admin generator.

Comment: I also work on both frameworks every day, and I concur with your answer. IMO ZF > sf. I've set up ZF with Doctrine2 and it's very easy using the zendcast, therefore I won't give sf the orm advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at Zend, but I did look at a couple of other frameworks before deciding on symfony.
For me it was the quality of the documentation - which for Symfony is excellent.
The thing with frameworks is that if you cannot use features because they are not well documented then they are not features at all.
It really boils down to your own requirements and how each feels - as you know the whole point of a framework is to work with it, if you are always adding extra code or exceptions then that framework is not right for you.

Comment: I've been using Zend Framework for years now and their docs are terrible. Very long, no real substance. You make an excellent point.